# Saving files using multithreading in python

Tags: python, hash, python-multithreading

I have a bunch of files that I want to load, process and save to another file, and since the size is huge I was using multithreading (in a for loop). However, only a few files get saved after getting processed. How do I make sure all of the files are saved?

Code snippets -
1. Main

```
for b in range(40):
    with open("/data/b{0}.pickle".format(str(b)), "rb") as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
    name="hash_table_"+str(b)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=generate_hash, args=(data,name))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

2. Processing files:

```
def generate_hash(m, name):
    hash_table = {}

    for index, elem in enumerate(m):

       ...
       # some code that updates hash_table
    save_hash_table(hash_table, name)

    return hash_table
```

3. Function for saving files:

```
def save_hash_table(hash_table, name):
    with open(os.path.join("/data/hashes", name+".pickle"), "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(hash_table, f)
```

Expected files - hash_table_0 to hash_table_39 pickle files, a total of 40 files

Actual files - around 20 files between hash_table_0 and hash_table_39

Comment: Is the "for process in processes" line supposed to be at the same level of indentation as for b in list_of_bs? In other words are you starting 40 processes and then joining them all afterwards? Might want to consider a Pool or some other resource manager.  Also does list_of_bs contain all non-duplicate numbers? If you replaced list_of_bs with range(40) do you get the same result?

Comment: @AndrewL Regarding list_of_bs, range(40) is what I used. After getting only half of the files saved than expected, I created a list of number corresponding to all the remaining ones and enumerated over them. Thanks for pointing that out; edited the post, as it corresponds to that problem. Regarding using Pool, I was not able to figure out how to save files while using Pool. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Sorry, just saw you responded. Do you still need help with this?

Comment: No problem. I figured out how to use 'Pool' in this case. The issue I faced then was it was taking up too much RAM. May be a bug in my code, but I finally got the files I needed. Thank you.